# How to get time stamp with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: timestamp

I am very new to Linux, I appreciate in advance for all the help.  I have searched online for various codes to get time stamp on a file. Ex: file.mp4.  But all the results I got was either invalid or showed an error.  (There is no file or directory by that name file.mp4). Please let me know what I can do in this situation.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `stat` command:

```
stat -c %X file.mp4
```

Instead of `%X` you can use any of these ( from `man stat`):

```
   %w     time of file birth, human-readable; - if unknown
   %W     time of file birth, seconds since Epoch; 0 if unknown
   %x     time of last access, human-readable
   %X     time of last access, seconds since Epoch
   %y     time of last data modification, human-readable
   %Y     time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch
   %z     time of last status change, human-readable
   %Z     time of last status change, seconds since Epoch
```

Remember that some of them like birth are not implemented yet. Also make sure you are in the same directory which your file is located.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to put these to work.  Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept the answer if you thing that it was helpful to you ;)